# Conditionally rendering when useEffect runs

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, axios

I am making an application in which I am calling 2 APIS on one screen. I want to call the first one when the screen renders for the first time and set response to some state values when it's done I am starting a count down function for approximately 3mins and when the count down ends I am calling the second API with data which are fetched from the first one and repeat the same process again for another cont down and re-renders the screen but I don't want to run the first API every time when screen re-renders.
Currently, I don't have code with me so hope you understood my problem any help will be appreciated.

first api call

```
const [stopTime, setStopTime] = useState('')

[period, setPeriod] = useState('')

const [minutes Left, setMinutes Left] = useState (null);

const [seconds Left, setSeconds Left]

= useState (null);

const [isTimeron, setTimeron] = useState (false);

const [issecondTime, setIsSecondTime] = useState(false) =

const userToken = user.userToken;

// console.log(userToken);

// function to get current period and result time 
const getGameData = ({token}) => {

const formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append('token', token);

axios({

method: 'POST',

url: BASE_URL + '/color_game.php',

data: formdata,

}).then (res ⇒>{

//console.log('first ${res.data. response.currentTimer}

setPeriod (res.data. response.timerId); 
setStopTime (res.data.response.currentTimer);

setIsSecond Time (true)

setTimeron (true);

}
```

Second api call

```
 const formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append('token', token);
 formdata.append('currentTimer', currentTimer);
formdata, append('timerId', timerId);

axios({

method: 'POST',

url: BASE_URL + '/color_game.php',

data: formdata,

}).then (res => {

// console.log('second");

console.log('second ${res.data.response.currentTimer} '); 
if (res.data. response.timerId != null) {
 setStopTime (res.data. response.currentTimer); 
setPeriod (res.data.response.timerId); 
setTimeron (true);

} else {

console.log('nothing');

} });

};
```

Cony down fuction

```
const countdown = () => {
if(isTimerOn){

var resultTime = new Date stopTime).getTime();

const time Interval=setInterval (() => {

var now = new Date().getTime();

var duration = resultTime - now; console.log(duration);

setMinutes Left (Math.floor( (duration % (1000 * 60

setSeconds Left (Math.floor( (duration % (1000 * 60)

if (duration <= 0) { 
clearInterval (timeInterval);

getGameDataSecondTime ({

token: userToken, timerId: period,

currentTimer: stopTime,

});

}

}, 1000);

}

};
```

Comment: I am using axios to call APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle 2 different actions in the same process using closure concept.

Here's an example (dependency is the trigger which could be a state value inside a timeout or anything):

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';


// First fetch function
const firstFetch=async()=>{};
// Second fetch function
const anotherFetch=async()=>{};

// An IIFE to handle the closure easily
const fetchFunction = (()=>{
  let firstTimeCall=true;

  // fetchFunction will be the below returned function with a closure(firstTimeCall)
  return ()=>{
    if(firstTimeCall){
      firstFetch();
      firstTimeCall=false;
    }else{
      anotherFetch();
    }
  }

})();

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFunction()
  }, [dependency]);

  return (....)
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I have tried your solution but I ant to store the response in state and it is not possible when I move fetch functions out side of component.

Comment: Check out the question again, I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 API calls. The first is called when the screen first renders and never again. The second depends on data from the first and is called every 3 minutes.

Effects are called based on the dependency array passed to them (e.g an empty array runs once). So I would base the code around that and do something like this:

```js
//  keeps track of whether the first api has been called
const [calledFirstApi, setCalledFirstApi] = useState(false);
// data from first api call will be stored here
const [data, setData] = useState({});
// store secondApi data here if it needs to trigger a re-render
const [otherData,setOtherData] = useState({});

const interval = useRef(null);
const time = 60*1000*3;

//dont know if your api is asynchronous or not
const callFirstApi = async ()=>{
  let apiData = await firstApi();
  setData(apiData);
}

const callSecondApi = async ()=>{
  //the second api call uses data from the first
  let apiData2 = await secondApi(data);
  setOtherData(apiData2)
}

// effect for first render
useEffect(()=>{
  callFirstApi();
  // mark api called
  setCalledFirstApi(true);
},[]);

//effect for when calledFirstApi changes
useEffect(()=>{
  // if false, do nothing/ return
  if(!calledFirstApi)
    return
  // when true start interval
  interval.current = setInterval(()=>{
    callSecondApi()
  }
  ,time)
  // the return of an effect is a cleanup function
  // (function will run when unmounting component)
  return ()=>clearInterval(interval.current);
}),[calledFirstApi]);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I have tried your solution but I am displaying a count down as per the response came from first api and by this solution cont down is set tu null.

Comment: Check out the question again, I have added the code